# Update Maps Overlay

Tags: android

I have some trouble understanding the concept of the Maps API in Android. Is it correct that every time I want to draw something new on the map, I create a new Overlay? This seems highly inefficient at a first glance. Is the whole layer structure baked down and I dont have to worry about performance at all or am I missing something like updateOverlay? 
Or would I just implement my own updateOverlay() method when I extend the Overlay class and call MapView.invalidate() afterwards?

Comment: Why not use [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/?hl=nl)?

Answer (score 0):

You create an overlay only once and the add it to the MapView. Then you need to call **postInvalidate()** on the *MapView*, so the new overlay will appear on the screen. Without this call, the overlay will be created, but will not show up.

Since the onResume() method in the activity lifecycle is always called when application starts or just wake up, you want to enable location tracking in onResume() and disable it in onPause(). There is a helpful method in **MyLocationOverlay class**: **runOnFirstFix()** This method allows you to set a code that will run as soon as we have location at all:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    whereAmI.enableMyLocation();
    whereAmI.runOnFirstFix( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mapController.setCenter(whereAmI.getMyLocation());
        }
    });
 }
```

After that, you don't need to do anything yourself, because the MyLocationOverlay is getting location updates and putting the blinking blue dot in that location.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    whereAmI.disableMyLocation();
}
```